# How to debug ThreadAbortException in an awaitable task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, task

I have the following code throwing `ThreadAbortException` in a production ASP.NET application (classic ASP.NET, not Core). I need some ideas/pointers/theories as to what might be happening. I don't have a luxury to change code for experimenting, and I could not get this to happen in my dev environment.

```
return await Task.Run(() => PostAsyncUri(request,headers));
```

The `PostAsyncUri` is a helper function that runs the `HttpClient`.

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsyncUri(HttpRequestMessage request,
    Dictionary<string, string> DefaultHeaders = null)
{
    try
    {
        var response = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            foreach (var h in DefaultHeaders)
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
            }
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the call stack looks like:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ThreadAbortException 
    Exception message: Thread was being aborted.   

at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)   
at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run(Task task, Boolean canInlineContinuationTask)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)  
at My.Business.Dependency.HttpClientProvider.<PostJsonWebRequestAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\My.Business\Dependencies\Concrete\HttpClientProvider.cs:line 122  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object stateMachine)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0(Object state)   
at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<Post>b__0()
at System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(Action action)
```

I know I could just await the output of `PostAsyncUri()` instead of wrapping it in a Task, but that could not be causing `ThreadAbortException` right?

Comment: Is it classic ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Not your problem but a couple of observations: 1. You shouldn't use [ServicePointManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager?view=net-6.0#remarks) anymore. Even if you do use it, you just need to set it once, not every time you make a request. 2. Don't [create a new HttpClient for each request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#instancing).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Classic

Comment: It probably is because you are wrapping it in a Task because you do not await the inner call the outer one will resolve before the other is done. I assume you are returning a response after doing this? Anyway, wrapping an awaitable in Task.Run wastes a threadpool thread. Its like buying a new car and having it towed around instead of just driving it.

Comment: @Crowcoder it's not accurate to say that the `Task.Run` with async delegate wastes a thread. A `ThreadPool` thread will be used just for instantiating/launching the `Task`, which is normally a miniscule work that completes in microseconds. After the `Task` is launched, the thread returns to the pool and it's available for other work.

Comment: Is this the real code? It looks like you're not even using the result

Comment: @JoePhillips The result is returned to the caller

Comment: @TheodorZoulias sure, it is miniscule, but if it is unnecessary, it is a waste IMO and probably the cause of the exception though there is not enough context to know what is happening after that call.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am pretty sure that the `Task.Run` is unnecessary, and it's probably related to the exception, but saying that it *"wastes a threadpool thread"* sounds like an exaggeration to me. It creates unrealistic expectations about the magnitude of the waste!

Comment: I think returning HttpRequestMessage in general is not great because it's only useful as long as the connection remains open. You may want to retrieve the response info immediately and then return that instead

Comment: we need to see what you're doing with the HttpResponseMessage after it is returned

Comment: Side note: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` why this? What will you do when you need to update to TLS1.3, why not just leave it up to the operating system?

Comment: OS is windows server 2008, it was choosing TLS1.1, so a developer had to force it.

Comment: @JoePhillips Reading the content as a stream immediately. The callstack shows the point of failure was the first return statement already listed in the quesiton.